# Android device discoverable via Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

It's obvious that Android device cannot act as a peripheral device.

But according to this group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/obC3g4bU9jU even central device can be made discoverable:

```
You can expose a server and the other can discover the service even if you are not able to advertise the service.
```

Can anybody show me, how to achieve this?

The only thing I need is to discover my Android device by another device via Bluetooth Low Energy.